# passing arguments to lambdas in lambdas in c++

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I am trying to come up with a way to pass functions to functions using lambdas like so, note that this is a reduced example `f0`, `f1` and `f...`will be numerical derivatives :

```
// innermost function
double g(double x, vector<double> pars){
  return x * pars[0] * pars[0];
}    
// some intermediate function
template <typename F>
auto f0(F const & f, double x, vector<double> pars) {
   return [f, pars](double x, vector<double> pars) {
     vector<double> pars_0(pars); 
     pars_0[0] = 0;
     return f(x, pars_0);
   };
}
// another intermediate function
template <typename F>
auto f1(F const & f, double x, vector<double> pars) {
   return [f, pars](double x, vector<double> pars) {
     vector<double> pars_1(pars); 
     pars_1[0] = 1;
     return f(x, pars_1);
   };
}
// selector function
template <typename F>
auto D(F const & f, double x, vector<double> pars, int degree) {
  if(0 == degree) {
    return f0(f, x, pars)(x, pars);
  } else {
    return f1(f, x, pars)(x, pars);
  }
}
```

This works so far that I can call `D(f, vars, 0)` or `D(f, vars, 1)` for example. Now I would like to call `D` on itself similar to `D(D(D(f, vars, 1), vars, 0), vars, 1)`. So I guess the return types of `D` have to be lambdas again:

```
template <typename F>
auto D(F const & f, double x, vector<double> pars, int degree) {
  if(0 == degree) {
    return [f, x, pars](F const & f, int x, vector<double> pars) {
      return D(f0(f, x, pars)(x, pars)); // <<< ?
      };
  } else {
    return // same stuff for the other function(s)
  }
}
```

I just don't know how to give them parameters. 
Like `D(D(f, 0), 1)(f_args)(inner_D_args)` or so (this doesn't work).
Ultimately this is where I want to go:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j ){
        for(int k = 0; k < 3; ++k ){
            ...
            sum += D(...(D(g, i), j)...,k) (pars of the lambdas); 
            // number of for loops depends on size of pars passed to f
        } 
    }
}
```

Where the `...` mean that the tower of `D(D(D(...)))` may become quiet large depending on the complexity of my model `g`.

- Is there an elegant solution to this?
- How would you define `D` ?
- (I am also happy for other ideas)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you mean. How exactly is the vector of doubles involved? You only ever use the first element in the vector. Is you final goal to use `D` without the for loops, but have it behave as if there was for loops equal to the size of `pars`?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're intending to do. However, I feel like I'd sooner user some kind of [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) (e.g something like [this](https://ideone.com/Hqi8YZ)) than having functions return lambdas that return lambdas that return... but maybe that doesn't apply here ?

Comment: @super the vector is used in `g` to define a function. In reality `g` has some more parameters so I kept one as an example, to justify having to pass something. The final goal is the nested `for` construction calling `D(D(...))` so `D` will be a numerical derivative function and its parameter `int degree` shall control the exponent as in `$D := \frac{ \partial^k f(x)  }{ \partial m^k}$` .

Comment: I think it would make sense to stop trying to do `D(D(D(D(...` and just use a simple loop.

Comment: @nwp the problem is I have `3**8` terms if I write them explicitly.

Comment: @Nhork I think the real problem is you don't have a unique type to represent your mathematical functions and rely on lambdas instead. Maybe you really want some kind of `MathFunction` class which stores an expression tree and does something akin to [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) ?

Comment: I still don't understand what you actually want to calculate. Can you write that in a complete and readable format? I can't tell if for example the lambdas are required or just an implementation attempt. Also I don't know where i, j and k come from in your ultimate example and how many there should be, what `(pars of the lambdas)` means and what `D` is supposed to do.